Notepad++ - mark only 12 characters between commas and list them
There are different amount of characters between commas. I had been trying to mark only the one with 12 characters between two commas in each row in Notepad++ and list them.
EX:
I want to turn this:
1234,abc1.2,34:56ab,MarkThis1234,UH3fefa33dfsuuF
123,ab-4.56,78:90,aBcD#1,mARKtHIS4321,AbCd,987

Into this:
MarkThis1234
mARKtHIS4321

Any help is appreciated, Thank you <3

([^,]{12})  Can you explain if this is OK ? expression

(?<=,)\w{12}(?=,)

@Luuk: Your regex also matches UH3fefa33dfsuuF

@KenWhite: That's because of the lousy description. Sure it's not between commas. But if we assume this input is a CSV, then it still is. (Because the description of CSV is ...., allowing it)

For the explanation of the regex, we can redirect the reader to: https://regex101.com/r/x7XVQF/1

@Luuk: I use RegexBuddy. Yours fails because it accounts only for the leading comma and 12 characters after it that are not commas. However, if character 13 is not a comma, yours won't correctly identify that it should not match UH3fefa33dfsuuF. I've tested it, which is why mine looks for a comma at both the left and right sides. The OP's example shows they want to match the two names from the sample text.

Doing a regex ReplaceAll of (^|,)([^,\r\n]{0,11}|[^,\r\n]{13,})(,|$) with \r\n converts all of the unwanted items into line breaks, then menu => Edit => Line operations => Remove empty lines removes the unwanted empty lines; leaving only the wanted text.
The regex has three parts. First begining-of-line or a comma. Lastly end-of-line or a comma. Between them is non-commas that are not exactly eleven characters in length. This last is achieved by looking for eith under 11, or over 11.
(^|,)                  Beginning-of-line, or a comma.
(                      Either
    [^,\r\n]{0,11}         0 to 11 characters, not a comma, LR or CR
|                      Or
    [^,\r\n]{13,}          13 or more characters, not a comma, LR or CR
)
(,|$)                  End-of-line, or a comma.

All three of theses groups could be non-captuting (i.e. using (?:...)) but I not shown that so as to concentrate on the important parts of the regex.

You, sir, just saved hours of my life from being wasted. Worked like a charm, Thank you!
